# $\forall f\in L^p : f\in L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

Yesterday I asked this question.

[exists $f\not\in L^1(X)$ such that $f\in L^p(X)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4581413/exists-f-not-in-l1x-such-that-f-in-lpx)

Which I already managed to solve, however that result generated me a doubt.

**My question**

$\exists (X,M,\mu)$ measurement space $\wedge$  $\exists p(1,\infty):\forall f\in L^p(X):\mu(X)=\infty$ $\wedge$  $f\in L^l(X)$

Under these conditions can such $X$ and $p$ exist?

**Update**

There will exist a space of Measurement X such that $\mu(X)=\infty$, and there will exist a $p(1,\infty)$ such that $L^p(X) \subseteq L^1(X)$

Comment: English is probably a better medium of expression than propositional logic.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you’re asking for a measure space $X$ with infinite measure and a $p \in (1,\infty)$ such that $L^p(X)$ is a subset of $L^1(X)$?

Comment: In this case, define a measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mu(A)=\infty$ whenever $A$ is nonempty. Then the only integrable function is the zero function, and hence $L^1 = L^p = \{0\}$ for every $p$.

Comment: Look at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1529073/27978, and extend the function to be zero on $(0,1)^c$.

Comment: Whoa, that is a big change in question.